# VHDL function that alters record fields disrupts untouched fields in Vivado Simulation

Tags: function, vhdl, record, vivado

I've spent too much time on this and am completely confused. I have a record type:

```
--t_dp_sosi record
TYPE t_fft_sosi_out IS RECORD  -- Source Out or Sink In
sync     : STD_LOGIC;   
bsn      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_dp_stream_bsn_w-1 DOWNTO 0);      -- ctrl
re       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_fft_out_dat_w-1 DOWNTO 0);            -- data
im       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_fft_out_dat_w-1 DOWNTO 0);            -- data
valid    : STD_LOGIC;                                           -- ctrl
sop      : STD_LOGIC;                                           -- ctrl
eop      : STD_LOGIC;                                           -- ctrl
empty    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_dp_stream_empty_w-1 DOWNTO 0);    -- info at eop
channel  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_dp_stream_channel_w-1 DOWNTO 0);  -- info at sop
err      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(c_dp_stream_error_w-1 DOWNTO 0);    -- info at eop (name field 'err' to avoid the 'error' keyword)
END RECORD;
```

and make an array type of it as such:
`TYPE t_fft_sosi_arr_out IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>) OF t_fft_sosi_out;`

All constants used to define the ranges of the field in the types are defined prior and in the same file. This type is used everywhere in my code as an interface and works well.

Now I have this function:

```
FUNCTION func_dp_stream_arr_combine_data_info_ctrl(dp : t_fft_sosi_arr_out; info, ctrl : t_fft_sosi_out) RETURN t_fft_sosi_arr_out IS
VARIABLE v_dp : t_fft_sosi_arr_out(dp'RANGE) := dp;       -- hold sosi data
BEGIN
FOR I IN dp'RANGE LOOP                          -- set sosi info
  v_dp(I).bsn     := info.bsn;      
  v_dp(I).channel := info.channel;  
  v_dp(I).empty   := info.empty;    
  v_dp(I).err     := info.err;      
  -- set sosi ctrl
  v_dp(I).valid := ctrl.valid;
  v_dp(I).sop   := ctrl.sop;
  v_dp(I).eop   := ctrl.eop;
  v_dp(I).sync  := ctrl.sync;
END LOOP;
RETURN v_dp;
END func_dp_stream_arr_combine_data_info_ctrl;
```

that is *meant* to take an array of records and alter some of each records' fields (minus the re and im field) to be like that of the `ctrl` or `info` records provided.

At some point in my code I use the function as such:

`nxt_src_out_arr <= func_dp_stream_arr_combine_data_info_ctrl(snk_in_arr, out_sosi, out_sosi);`

and it completely messes up my re and im fields see here (sorry it is a little blurry):
[image: Input and output when using function]

`snk_in_arr` and `nxt_src_out_arr` are both ```t_fft_sosi_arr_out(g_nof_streams-1 DOWNTO 0);`` arrays where g_nof_streams is a defined generic. If I do not go via the function as such:

`nxt_src_out_arr <= snk_in_arr;`

Then the re and im fields match and all is well:
[image: Input and output when not using the function]

I'm running this on Vivado 2020.2 on Windows 10.
I've found that this issue does not occur with Vivado 2020.1 (on Mint or Windows 10).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with an MCVE. But I'd be inclined to add (in the loop in the function) `ASSERT v_dp(i).re = dp(i).re REPORT "v_dp initialisation FAILED" severity FAILURE;` and if it triggers, ship the MCVE off to Xilinx for comment. Workarounds : copy dp(i) into v_dp(i) at start of loop body instead of relying on the initialisation, if that doesn't work.

Comment: Quartus has no functional simulator - it only has a post synthesis simulation tool. Have you tried in another simulator - GHDL for example? without an MCVE it will be hard to see whats going on. What version of vivado is it? are you using the newest 2021.1?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "1. Questions *seeking debugging help* ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." If your silicon works that would cast an eye upon the Vivado Simulator (version?) as would another simulator.

Comment: Apologies all I do realise I should've provided an MCVE, I'll try create one. I've not tried another simulator since my design contains Vivado XPM blocks which I've had trouble simulating with other software. I'm using Vivado 2020.2. When I follow @user_1818839 advice and put the assert statement in the function loop I do get a failure... So I'll try your workaround for now and put together an MCVE to try reproduce the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Also, the assert still triggers even if I do the copy at the top inside the loop instead of the initialisation:

```v_dp(I).re := dp(I).re;
  v_dp(I).im := dp(I).im;
  ASSERT v_dp(i).re = dp(i).re REPORT "v_dp initialisation FAILED" severity FAILURE;```

Comment: https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/52331?language=en_US suggests there are limitations to Vivado's support for records in other areas, but variable assignment and initialisation is so basic ...

Comment: If you look 3 out of the 8 record elements of `out_sosi` are effected and all from the `info` parameter. The [MCVE]() would assure us there aren't multiple drivers for `out_sosi`.  Multiple drivers can be caused by *longest static prefix*, possibly using a non-static `t_fft_sosi_arr_out` type object index.

Comment: Hi all, I tried to make an MCVE, but found a different issue. The function still does not do what it is supposed to but it does not alter untouched fields. Please see [here][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404916/vhdl-record-fields-do-not-update-in-simulation-in-vivado-2020-2]. I realise creating a new post for the MCVE is not best practice, but since it gave a differing issue, I thought it wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this appears to be a version issue for both this problem and the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404916/vhdl-record-fields-do-not-update-in-simulation-in-vivado-2020-2/69406378#69406378).

As you can see, in Vivado 2020.1 (below) `nxt_src_out_arr` and `snk_in_arr` now match after running it through the function in question:

[image: matching results]

Thanks all, I'd log this issue with Vivado but I am struggling to do so. I've also logged in several times and filled in a survey in an attempt to reach the community forum. When I finally got there,
I get errors when selecting 'Vivado' as my topic for my question. Hopefully they find this issue here.