# VHDL record fields do not update in Simulation in Vivado 2020.2

Tags: vhdl, simulation, record, vivado

I first noticed this issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364477/vhdl-function-that-alters-record-fields-disrupts-untouched-fields-in-vivado-simu) post here. I've now gone ahead and made an MCVE. The DUT:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.top_pkg.all;

entity top is
  Port ( 
      clk : in std_logic;
      ce : in std_logic;
      input_custom_arr : in custom_record_array(4 downto 0);
      info : in custom_record;
      ctrl : in custom_record;
      output_custom_arr : out custom_record_array(4 downto 0)
  );
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is

begin
    process(clk)
    begin
      if(ce = '1' and rising_edge(clk)) then
        output_custom_arr <= func_manipulate_custom_record_array(input_custom_arr, info, ctrl);
      end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The package it uses that contains the custom function and types:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

package top_pkg is
    type custom_record is record
        data_1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        data_2 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
        sync   : std_logic;   
        enable : std_logic;
    end record;

    type custom_record_array is ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>) of custom_record;

    FUNCTION func_manipulate_custom_record_array(dp : custom_record_array; info, ctrl : custom_record) RETURN custom_record_array;
    end package;

package body top_pkg is

    FUNCTION func_manipulate_custom_record_array(dp : custom_record_array; info, ctrl : custom_record) RETURN custom_record_array is
        VARIABLE v_dp : custom_record_array(dp'RANGE) := dp;
        begin
            for I IN dp'RANGE LOOP
                v_dp(I).sync := info.sync;
                v_dp(I).enable := ctrl.enable;
            end loop;
        return v_dp;
        END func_manipulate_custom_record_array;
end package body;
```

And the testbench to simulate:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.top_pkg.all;

entity tb_top is
end tb_top;

architecture Behavioral of tb_top is
constant half_period : time := 10ns;
constant num_of_clocks : integer := 10;

signal input_custom_arr : custom_record_array(4 downto 0);
signal output_custom_arr : custom_record_array(4 downto 0);
signal info : custom_record := ((others=>'0'),(others=>'0'),'1','0');
signal ctrl : custom_record := ((others=>'0'),(others=>'0'),'0','1');
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal ce : std_logic := '0';
signal i : integer := 0;

begin
    -- continuous clock
    process 
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for half_period;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for half_period;

        if (i = num_of_clocks) then
            wait;
        elsif (i < 5) then
            input_custom_arr(i).data_1 <= std_logic_vector(TO_SIGNED(i,4));
            input_custom_arr(i).data_2 <= std_logic_vector(TO_SIGNED(4-i,4));
            i <= i + 1;
        elsif ( i = 5) then
            ce <= '1';
            i <= i + 1;
        else
            i <= i + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    --DUT
    u_dut : entity work.top
    port map(
        clk => clk,
        ce => ce,
        input_custom_arr => input_custom_arr,
        output_custom_arr => output_custom_arr,
        info => info,
        ctrl => ctrl
    );
end Behavioral;
```

If you simulate, you get the following wave window:
[image]

After the 7th period, you will note that the sync and enable fields of the `output_custom_arr` array do not get updated as the function specifies. From the testbench, I'd expect that the sync and enable fields of every element in the `output_custom_arr` be `'1'`.

This issue is different to what was occurring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364477/vhdl-function-that-alters-record-fields-disrupts-untouched-fields-in-vivado-simu) where the untouched fields were being altered. However, unless I've made an error here, does this reaffirm Vivado's struggle to simulate records correctly? At lease for version 2020.2 on Windows 10?

Thank you.
Talon Myburgh.

Comment: `constant half_period : time := 10ns;`  IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal." The consequence is a lack of portability to those tools enforcing this requirement. Note no declarations found in IEEE package numeric_std are used in your package and first two entity/architecture pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this appears to be a version issue for both this problem and the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364477/vhdl-function-that-alters-record-fields-disrupts-untouched-fields-in-vivado-simu).

In Vivado 2020.1 on Windows 10, for the exact same project as above, I get what we would expect in Simulation:

[image]

I do not know how far this issue extends in Vivado 2020.2 but I'd recommend avoiding designs with arrays of records in that version for the time being.

Thanks all.

Comment: I didn't realise you had asked a second question! Your "MCVE" is missing a bunch of library and use clauses; after hunting those down I can see Vivado 2021.1 produces the above rather than the result in the question, so apparently Xilinx has fixed it (this one at least!) again.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure which libraries I've missed. I copied those files straight from a working project (where all files are in the same library). Good to know they have fixed it.

Comment: looking again at your sources I have to retract that comment : something weird seems to have happened during my C&P into Vivado. Hmmm...